# Converting a cURL command into C# UWP

Tags: c#, json, curl, uwp, httpclient

I have the following CURL command that returns a correct result (*ID & Password have been changed to protect the innocent*):

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"isPersistent":true,"password":"My-Password","username":"test@yahoo.com"}' https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/CustomerPortal/Auth/Auth.svc/Authenticate
```

I have written the following Windows UWP C# code to do the equivalent, but I get a ERROR 400 response when I run it:

```
//Create an HTTP client object
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json, text/plain, */*");

Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/CustomerPortal/Auth/Auth.svc/Authenticate");

Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new     Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
string httpResponseBody = "";

try
{
    //Send the POST request
    httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, new HttpStringContent("{\"username\":\"test@yahoo.com\",\"password\":\"My-Password\",\"isPersistent\":true}"));
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var x = 1;
    httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Thanks!

var i = 1;

Comment: Is the try-parse-add method actually returning true? I want to say you just need `application/json` for it as well, without the other content types.

Comment: I changed the TryParseAdd to only add application/json. Checked to make sure it was actually being added, which it was. This did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept` specifies the `Accept` header for your request. In your case you need to specify a `Content-Type` as well.

To add the `Content-Type` header to the request, you should use a different constructor for the [`HttpStringContent` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpstringcontent):

```
public HttpStringContent(String content, UnicodeEncoding encoding, String mediaType)
```

So the right usage would be:

```
httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(
       requestUri, 
       new HttpStringContent( 
           "{\"username\":\"test@yahoo.com\",\"password\":\"My-Password\",\"isPersistent\":true}", 
           UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
           "application/json" ) );
```